# List items on eBay API with best offer enabled

Tags: c#, ebay-api

So far I have been trying to list items on ebay and allow Best Offers items.

I have tried this:

```
if (_eBayListingUtility.AllowBestOffer)
{
    item.BestOfferEnabled = true;

    item.BestOfferEnabledSpecified = true;

    item.BestOfferDetails = new BestOfferDetailsType
    {
        BestOfferEnabled = true,
        BestOfferEnabledSpecified = true,
    };

    item.ListingDetails = new ListingDetailsType
    {
        MinimumBestOfferMessage = _eBayListingUtility.MinimumBestOfferMessage,
        MinimumBestOfferPrice = new AmountType
        {
            currencyID = CurrencyUtility.GetDefaultCurrencyCodeType(_context.Site),
            Value = (double)_eBayListingUtility.MinimumBestOffer
        },
        BestOfferAutoAcceptPrice = new AmountType
        {
            currencyID = CurrencyUtility.GetDefaultCurrencyCodeType(_context.Site),
            Value = (double)_eBayListingUtility.MinimumBestOffer
        }
    };
}
```

But that does not change anything. FYI, `AllowBestOffer` is a boolean for an item to be listed, and an `item` is an `ItemType` ebay class item.

I have tried this on an auction or fixed price item based on the `AddItem` api call, but all my items (ex: http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/110141411066?hash=item19a4dce3e0#ht_849wt_1397) does not show the "Best offer" button. So how can I achieve what I need to do?